# Using ARRAYFORMULA combined with IMPORTRANGE to import from multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to say at the start I am NOT going to use Apps Script or any other tools. I just want to know if this can be done using plain Google Sheets formulas.

The goal is to import the same content from multiple sheets on a spreadsheet.

`=FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(A1,ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(12)&"!E2:F500"))),ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(A1,ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(12)&"!F2:F500")))<>"")`

This is my current working code, but when I try to use it all it gives me is the contents of 1!E2:F500 and not any of the other sheets. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Note: I have also tried moving around the ARRAYFORMULAS to basically everywhere they could go. Still no luck.

Edit: This question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

REDUCE is very helpful when you need to stack sequentally imported ranges. Try with this formula and let me know:

```
=REDUCE({"Header 1","Header 2"},SEQUENCE(12),LAMBDA(a,v,
{a;IFNA(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE(A1,v&"!E2:F500"),IMPORTRANGE(A1,v&"!F2:F500")<>""),{"",""})}))
```

Comment: Tried to use it but I got
`Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.`

Edit: Nevermind, I made a slight edit and it was fixed.

Comment: Could you share some sample sheet to test?

Comment: It's all sorted out don't worry about it. Thanks for the help!